# TCoolBar band resizing problem in Delphi 10.3

Tags: delphi, vcl

I put a `TCoolBar` component into a brand new project in `Delphi 10.3`. There are some bands in a row. When I resize one band, the others on its right in the same row resize too. I can decrease or increase the band size, the others on the right always grow by the difference. If I resize the form all the band gone wild. They all increase their sizes.

The error does not occure if I create a band by the band editor. It occures when I drop down some `TActionToolBar` into the `TCoolBar`.

The CoolBar AutoSize does not set. The bands or TActionToolBar has not a property like this.

The pas file:

```
unit Unit2;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.ToolWin, Vcl.ComCtrls,
  Vcl.PlatformDefaultStyleActnCtrls, System.Actions, Vcl.ActnList, Vcl.ActnMan,
  Vcl.ActnCtrls;

type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    ActionManager1: TActionManager;
    CoolBar1: TCoolBar;
    ActionToolBar1: TActionToolBar;
    ActionToolBar2: TActionToolBar;
    ActionToolBar3: TActionToolBar;
    ActionToolBar4: TActionToolBar;
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form2: TForm2;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

end.
```

The dpr file:

```
object Form2: TForm2
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form2'
  ClientHeight = 405
  ClientWidth = 635
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  OnCreate = FormCreate
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object CoolBar1: TCoolBar
    Left = 0
    Top = 0
    Width = 635
    Height = 65
    Bands = <
      item
        Control = ActionToolBar1
        ImageIndex = -1
        Width = 148
      end
      item
        Break = False
        Control = ActionToolBar2
        ImageIndex = -1
        Width = 477
      end
      item
        Control = ActionToolBar3
        ImageIndex = -1
        Width = 146
      end
      item
        Break = False
        Control = ActionToolBar4
        ImageIndex = -1
        Width = 479
      end>
    FixedSize = True
    object ActionToolBar1: TActionToolBar
      Left = 11
      Top = 0
      Width = 135
      Height = 25
      Caption = 'ActionToolBar1'
      Color = clMenuBar
      ColorMap.DisabledFontColor = 7171437
      ColorMap.HighlightColor = clWhite
      ColorMap.BtnSelectedFont = clBlack
      ColorMap.UnusedColor = clWhite
      Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
      Font.Color = clBlack
      Font.Height = -11
      Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
      Font.Style = []
      ParentFont = False
      Spacing = 0
    end
    object ActionToolBar2: TActionToolBar
      Left = 163
      Top = 0
      Width = 468
      Height = 25
      Caption = 'ActionToolBar2'
      Color = clMenuBar
      ColorMap.DisabledFontColor = 7171437
      ColorMap.HighlightColor = clWhite
      ColorMap.BtnSelectedFont = clBlack
      ColorMap.UnusedColor = clWhite
      Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
      Font.Color = clBlack
      Font.Height = -11
      Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
      Font.Style = []
      ParentFont = False
      Spacing = 0
    end
    object ActionToolBar3: TActionToolBar
      Left = 11
      Top = 27
      Width = 133
      Height = 25
      Caption = 'ActionToolBar3'
      Color = clMenuBar
      ColorMap.DisabledFontColor = 7171437
      ColorMap.HighlightColor = clWhite
      ColorMap.BtnSelectedFont = clBlack
      ColorMap.UnusedColor = clWhite
      Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
      Font.Color = clBlack
      Font.Height = -11
      Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
      Font.Style = []
      ParentFont = False
      Spacing = 0
    end
    object ActionToolBar4: TActionToolBar
      Left = 161
      Top = 27
      Width = 470
      Height = 25
      Caption = 'ActionToolBar4'
      Color = clMenuBar
      ColorMap.DisabledFontColor = 7171437
      ColorMap.HighlightColor = clWhite
      ColorMap.BtnSelectedFont = clBlack
      ColorMap.UnusedColor = clWhite
      Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
      Font.Color = clBlack
      Font.Height = -11
      Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
      Font.Style = []
      ParentFont = False
      Spacing = 0
    end
  end
  object ActionManager1: TActionManager
    Left = 248
    Top = 160
    StyleName = 'Platform Default'
  end
end
```

Is there any solution for this problem?